# How to insert data in laravel 5.2 using ajax serialize() function?

Tags: ajax, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having a trouble implementing data insertion using laravel by passing data from my view using serialize() function to my controller.I am just starting to play around laravel but I am now stacked on this. Begging someone to help me solve this. Thanks a lot. Below are my codes.

**Product Form**

```
<form class="form-horizontal prod-form" id="prod-form" style="background-color: #e2e2e2;" method="post" enctype="multiprodt/form-data">
          <fieldset>

            <div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-success alert-add-success">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
              <center><h4>Data successfully saved.</h4></center>
            </div>

            <address></address>

           <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" class="prod_id" id="prod_id" value="">
           <input type="hidden" name="_token"  value="<?= csrf_token(); ?>">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputActivity" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[pharmaceutical]" id="inputPharmaceutical" placeholder="Product name" value="" style="width:260px;height:40px;" onchange="" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputActivity" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Description</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[description]" id="inputDescription" placeholder="Description" value="" style="width:260px;height:40px;" onchange="" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputActivity" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Unit</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[unit]" id="inputUnit" placeholder="Unit" value="" style="width:260px;height:40px;" onchange="" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputVenue" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Price</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[price]" id="inputPrice" placeholder="Price" value="" style="width:260px;height:40px;" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputSponsors" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Quantity</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[quantity]" id="inputQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" value="" style="width:260px;height:40px;" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="inputSponsors" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Amount</label>
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prod[amount]" id="inputAmount" placeholder="Amount" value="" style="width:260px;height:40px;" required>
              </div>
            </div>

             <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button class="btn btn-primary submit-prod">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </fieldset>
        </form>
```

**Javascript Function when submit button is clicked**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".submit-prod").click(function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

  var button_text = $(this).text();

   alert($("#prod-form").serialize());

   $.post("{{ url('/addprod') }}",$("#prod-form").serialize(),function(data){

       if(data.notify == "Success"){
         console.log(data.notify);
       }

     },"json");

   }); //end

 </script>
```

**Route.php**

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

 Route::post('addprod', 'Product\ProductController@store');

 Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

 });
```

**ProductController.php**

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Product;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Product\Product as Product;

 class ProductController extends Controller
 {

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}


public function create(){

}

public function store(Request $request){

    //$product = new Product;

    $prod_details = $request->all();

    $query = Product::create($prod_details);

      if($query){
        $notification = "Success";
      } else{
        $notification = "Failed";
      }

      echo json_encode(array('notify'=>$notification));


   }


 }
```

Model: Product.php

```
<?php

 namespace App\Product;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Product extends Model
 {
   //
 }
```

Sample Input:
[image]

Error Output:

[image]

Comment: Are you uploading any file too?

Comment: No sir. Its just all user inputted text

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue is the csrf-token please user form helper class to declare your forms or declare the token. Else you will take millenniums to solve your problem